# How does this gem hook into your error handling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to understand how gems work, and how you can create a gem to override or add additional functionality to a rails 3 application.

This is a error catching gem that posts errors via http to a server.

To install it you simply add the gem, and then it creates an initializer with your api key.

This part I get so far, but I need help understand the execution of the gem and how it hooks into rails.

The relevant file that I found are:

https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/lib/airbrake/rails.rb

Where it adds methods to the `ActionController` class:

```
  if defined?(ActionController::Base)
    ActionController::Base.send(:include, Airbrake::Rails::ActionControllerCatcher)
    ActionController::Base.send(:include, Airbrake::Rails::ErrorLookup)
    ActionController::Base.send(:include, Airbrake::Rails::ControllerMethods)
    ActionController::Base.send(:include, Airbrake::Rails::JavascriptNotifier)
  end
```

And at the bottom of the file it executes it:

```
Airbrake::Rails.initialize


1. You add the gem to your GEMFILE, and call bundle.
2. You run the generator which creates the initializer file:
```

So when my rails application starts up, it will go through the initializer.

Is this where the gem will get instantiated and then somewhere down the line run the `Airbrake::Rails.initialize` method when it finishes parsing the `/lib/airbrake/rails.rb` file?

I can see the initializer code in the `railtie.rb` file:

https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/lib/airbrake/railtie.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
  Airbrake.configure(true) do |config|
    config.logger           ||= ::Rails.logger
    config.environment_name ||= ::Rails.env
    config.project_root     ||= ::Rails.root
    config.framework        = "Rails: #{::Rails::VERSION::STRING}"
  end

  if defined?(::ActionController::Base)
    require 'airbrake/rails/javascript_notifier'
    require 'airbrake/rails/controller_methods'

    ::ActionController::Base.send(:include, Airbrake::Rails::ControllerMethods)
    ::ActionController::Base.send(:include, Airbrake::Rails::JavascriptNotifier)
  end
end
```

This seems to make sense now since it is running this code after the initializer runs and sets up the configuration, it sends the `ControllerMethods`, etc to the base class.

But this seems to duplicate the code I posted earlier when things were already being sent to the `ApplicationController` file in the call to `Airbrake::Rails.initialize`.

I am hoping someone can tell me how things execute and it what order as I just don't see how this process works in a clear way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duplicated code is here to support different versions of rails.

**Rails 2.X**

Rails 2.X looks for `rails/init.rb` to determine if a gem is a rails plugin or not. The airbrake one contains a single line:

```
require 'airbrake/rails'
```

Your summary of the next step was spot-on:

> Is this where the gem will get instantiated and then somewhere down
>   the line run the Airbrake::Rails.initialize method when it finishes
>   parsing the /lib/airbrake/rails.rb file?

**Rails 3.X**

Rails 3.X plugins often inherit from `Rails::Railtie`, to be able to define rake tasks, plug into the boot sequence or [do a lot of other interesting things](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html).

The following line in `lib/airbrake.rb` checks the availability of the `Railtie` class (equivalent to checking if you're running rails 3) and defines `Airbrake::Railtie` if it's the case:

```
require 'airbrake/railtie' if defined?(Rails::Railtie)
```

When defining a `Railtie`, you don't have to run it manually (the equivalent of `Airbrake::Rails.initialize`), subclassing `Rails::Railtie` is enough to create your plugin.

**Additional reading**

If you want to understand how rails 3 achieves its modularity, the following documentation will be quite helpful:

- [Rails::Railtie](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html)
- [Rails::Engine](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html)
- [Rails::Plugin](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Plugin.html)
- [Rails::Application](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html)

Comment: thanks, btw, is it possible to create a gem and test it in a rails web app at the same time?  or do you create a gem separately? want to learn this stuff!

Comment: @Blankman Using `rails plugin new` creates a plugin skeleton with a dummy test app in `test/dummy` (or `spec/dummy`) to do the integration/functional tests, but nothing prevents you from running this rails app. That's what I'm doing because I like having an example app in the gem repository.